# What exactly are generalized coordinates and how do they differ from regular coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm trying to learn the basics of Hamiltonian mechanics, which typically distinguishes itself from Newtonian mechanics as being described in terms of "generalized coordinates and momenta".

What exactly is meant by the term "generalized coordinates"?  How do they differ from ordinary coordinates?

When I say "ordinary coordinates", I interpret it to mean a coordinate system obtained by a combination of pre-specified linearly independent vectors.

Comment: What about [Wikipedia's take on that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind:  I don't understand why the term "generalized" is needed... In my opinion (naive as it may be), coordinates are coordinates.  What is the fundamental property that makes one coordinate system "generalized" and another not?

Comment: A coordinate is simply a number. In high school we teach that three of these numbers are sufficient to label physical points in space. If we do teach properly in high school, then we do not pretend that these labels have to have some particular structure (like in case of orthogonal coordinate systems), even though some students may imagine that to be the case based on the one and only example of a coordinate system they are being shown. In my high school, by the way, we did learn about polar and spherical coordinates.

Comment: The generalized, can in first be understood as the needed coordinates to describe the motion of a system. In three dimensions, let's say x,y,z, assume you have a point body able to move only on x,y plane. Then the generalized coordinates are not the three(x,y,z) but x and y, with z=0. You can also have a different coordinates system, say polar(r,u) which gives you again the needed coordinates to describe the system.

Comment: Allow me to say that now I think you can understand the Wikipedia article mentioned above.

Comment: You may also search configuration space(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space) on the web or in books.